# What is the inverse of Energy?

Tags: energy

Is there a name for the inverse of Energy $1/E$ or the inverse of the Joule $1/Joule$? It comes up if you divide the mass-energy relation by energy (so you get a constant of 1).

Comment: When you divide $E = mc^2$ by $E$, you get both sides dimensionless. What do you want $1/E$ for?

Comment: Nothing special, but i'm fascinated by the idea that instead of writing the laws of the universe as 'relations' between quantities you can also write them as 'boundaries' defined by such constants. e.g. $mc^2/E=1$ I'm curious if $1/E$ could be considered some special kind of property/quantity (e.g. entropy but not really in the thermodynamic sense)

Comment: You "lose something in the translation" when you take physics concepts and formulate them into something that is purely mathematical.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Time.

Long answer:
The conjugate quanta of energy is time, one can look at energy as the generalized momenta associated with time.

With that is mind one can go to QM essentials and proclaim:
$$
\Delta E \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$

As a consequence, one can say:
$$
\frac{1}{E}\propto t
$$
Edit:
Even longer answer:
I agree with gented below, that this answer can be misleading and promote a wrong view of physics, hence this edit.

From the viewpoint of Noether theorem, and its meaning for field theory, one can look at transformations as operators. Every linear transformation that is continuously connected to the identity transformation can be written down as:
$$
F(\vec{x}+\vec{dx})=F+dF,
$$
with $dF=\sum\frac{dF}{dx_i}dx_i$. If we further assign a deformation parameter $\alpha$ such that the change in function is due to the deformation parameter alone we can write:
$$
dF=\sum \frac{dF}{dx_i}\frac{dx_i}{d\alpha}d\alpha =d\alpha \left(\sum\frac{dx_i}{d\alpha}\frac{d}{dx_i}\right)F
$$
The quantity $\left(\sum\frac{dx_i}{d\alpha}\frac{d}{dx_i}\right)$ is called the generator of the transformation such that the transformation can be written as an exponent like so:
$$
T_a=e^{Ga}.
$$
Notice this satisfies $T_0=I$. There are several ways to find the generator(s) of a transformation, but it so happens that the generators of spatial translations is momentum such that if you want the transformation $x\rightarrow x+a$, it is given by $T_a=e^{\frac{i\hat{P}a}{\hbar}}$ where $\hat{P}$ is given by
$$
\hat{P}= -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
$$

It is in this sense that we can identify reciprocal physical quantities, the generator of $x$ translation is momentum, so in a sense momentum is the reciprocal of location. It turns out that the generator of time translations is the Hamiltonian, as the time translation operator can be written as 
$$
U(t,t+\Delta t)=e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\mathcal{H}dt},
$$
Where the Hamiltonian represents the Energy of the system, and is promoted to an operator status.
Under some conditions this can be simplified further to the following:
$$
U=e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}\Delta t},
$$
so in this sense the energy is the 'reciprocal' of time.

There are volumes of information and infrastructure missing from this answers, but in a nutshell this was all that I could manage. 
This 'reciprocity' can and is used say in elementary particle physics as a 'rule of thumb' for particle decay times, where the more massive the particle the faster it should decay. Although this is just a guesstimate technique and more often than not doesn't really work.

Comment: I don't think that this addresses the question.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right, however it IS a common observation and explains some of the more advanced conventions, such as $\Gamma$ which is a rate ($\frac{1}{t}$) but is expressed in mass or energy... There are more examples, but that one just pops into mind right now...

Comment: @garyp This answer is in a surprising direction but i think it does address the question. Because so far this is the only answer i can assume the 'official' answer is "there's no official inverse of energy"

Comment: @BeastRaban If $\hbar$ is Planck's constant can we consider it dimensionless? I'm really no expert i physics :S but isn't the relation you wrote equivalent to $$
Joule Second \geq \frac{Joule Second}{2}
$$ ?

Comment: You can look up "Natural units" or "geometric units"...
It's common practice to make theoretical derivations in units where $\hbar=c=G=K_{B}=1$, and after the fact reintroduce them if one needs to find a theoretical value (to compare to experimental results).
As for the dimensional analysis: the only importance is the units be the same. dimensionless number do not matter, these are not equations but auxiliary tools.

Comment: This answer is very dangerous (especially for the non-physicists): a lot of things are left untold and the context isn't precisely specified.